# Fixing line feeds problems in git

Tags: git, diff

I accidentally replaced my CRLF to LF line endings during a commit.
The file history now look like this:

```
+---------+-----------+
| Version | Line Feed |
+---------+-----------+
|    4    | CRLF      |
|    3    | CRLF      | << changed all LFs back to CRLFs
|    2    | LF        | << mistake introduced here
|    1    | CRLF      |
+---------+-----------+
```

The problem is that this file is now identified as a binary file (even after I have manually corrected the problem in version 3).  This resulted in `diff`, `blame` and other tools to stop working as expected on this text file.

I tried setting `*.xml crlf diff` in `./git/info/attributes` but it only works for `diff` not for `blame`, also suspecting I might face problems with merge conflicts. It also gives me `LF will be replaced by CRLF` warnings when committing this file, indicating that the attributes settings are not sufficient.

This is on a Windows OS with `autocrlf = true` set. 
 
 
**How do I get git to identify it as a text file again?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 'crlf' attribute is deprecated. It has been replaced by the 'text' and 'eol' attributes, but you most likely do not need to use the 'eol' attribute.

Git was never intended to store CRLF line endings internally so this may require history rewriting to completely fix. The commits that changed the line ending will be the earliest commits that blame will see because it thinks the entire file was rewritten (it was).

One way to try and prevent this from happening again is to add `* text=auto` to `.gitattributes` and commiting that file to the repo.

More info about this can be found at the [gitattributes man page](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes).